# Why do you need the following sequence in String manipulation in Android,

Tags: android, html, string

```
EditExt name;
TextView result;
private void applyFormat() {
String format=getString(R.string.funky_format);
String simpleResult=String.format(format,TextUtils.htmlEncode(name.getText().toString()));
result.setText(Html.fromHtml(simpleResult));
}
}
```

The question I have why need to use htmlEncode first and do that Html.fromHtml.   And what does  it means by saying converting entity-escaped HTML into a Spanned object via Html.fromHtml().  What is really a Spanned object? definitionwise.

Comment: Actually the "monkey action" indicates that people may know, but don't want to answer because the quality of the question is too low. *"kind of sucks"* is not the correct attitude to deal with that issue. In the end it comes down to this: If you want people to do you a favor and give you an answer, do them a favor and write a good question that meets their standards. *(the issue with this question is mainly that it doesn't show any research effort imho)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question I have why need to use htmlEncode first

You do not "need" to do anything.

However, in this example, any HTML entered into the `EditText` will be rendered in the result as HTML source code, by use of `htmlEncode()`. If you skip that step, any HTML entered into the `EditText` will be part of the HTML converted into the Spannable. IOW, if you type `<b>foo</b>` into the `EditText`, with `htmlEncode()`, you see `<b>foo</b>` in the output; without `htmlEncode()`, you see **foo**.

> What is really a Spanned object?

It is a Java interface. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html):

> This is the interface for text that has markup objects attached to ranges of it.